# Paginate posts which are displayed with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, kaminari

In my rails app, I am rendering posts with ajax:

```
<%= link_to explore_posts_path, remote: true %>
```

In my controller:

```
def explore 
  @posts = Post.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In explore.js.erb:

```
$('.explore-wrapper').append('\
   <div class="explore-posts col-xs-9">\
     <%= j render @posts %>\
    </div>\
');
```

However, I'd like to paginate those posts with Kaminari. I managed to have Kaminari to work in my app on other pages, but posts weren't displayed with AJAX, they were displayed on page load.

I changed my explore.js.erb file:

```
$('.explore-wrapper').append('\
    <div class="explore-posts col-xs-9">\
        <%= j render @posts %>\
        <%= paginate @posts %>\
    </div>\
  ');
```

But now there aren't any posts displayed, so it "broke" the callback.

How can I display with AJAX paginated posts (with Kaminari) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html generated by Kaminari is not escaped.

`<%= j(paginate(@posts)) %>`